# Why template chooses T equals int when implicity passed uint16_t?

Tags: c++

I have next snippet

```
class Mapper { //not templated!
...
template<class T>
static QList<quint16> toPduValue(T value)
{
    constexpr quint8 registersPerT = sizeof(T) / sizeof(quint16);

    return buildPduValue((registersPerT < 1) ? (quint16) value : value);
}


template<class T>
static QList<quint16> buildPduValue(T value)
{
...
}
...
}
```

But when to  `toPduValue` passed `bool`, and then to `buildPduValue` passed `(quint16) value` `buildPduValue` specializes like `<int>`?

callstack

[image]

debugger shows next expression
[image]

Comment: Which is the value of `std::common_type_t<bool, quint16>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 , I explicity cast `bool` to `quint16` when `(quint16)value`. So, it is equal to passing clear `quint16`. Template has not to choose between `bool` and `quint16`. But why `<int>` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your ternary expression is `int`.  You can verify this by trying to compile this code and looking carefully at the error message:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
char * foo = (2 < 3) ? (uint16_t)2 : (bool)1;
```

The error message will be something like:

> error: invalid conversion from '**int**' to 'char*'

You could just apply a cast to your ternary expression to cast it to the specific type you want.

Or you could ensure that both possible values of the ternary expression have the same type, so that the overall expression will have the same type.

Or you could use a `if` statement instead of a ternary expression.

Note that your ternary expression can only have one type; it doesn't have a different type depending on which case was evaluated.

Comment: But why debugger calculates ternal like `quint16`? It is shown on last screen.

Qt6 Editor

Comment: Maybe you evaluated that statement in a context where `T` was `quint16`, or maybe the debugger does not properly implement this aspect of the C++ language (i.e. the debugger has a bug in it).  I trust compiler error messages more than a string in the UI of a debugger.

Comment: Can you explain this cpp logic?  Why T of called template method doesn't choose right at  runtime (`quint16` or `T` depending on evaluting expression )? 

Why it is choosen common type of ternary expressions types ? Mixing executing branches is a strange logic. What benefits?

Comment: `You could just apply a cast to your ternary expression to cast it to the specific type you want.`

I want to choose between `quint16` and `T` when calling `buildPduValue`. I don't know how to cast ternary expr to one of them depending of context. How it is looks like?
`buildPduValue<(...) ? quint16  : T>(...);` I don't know analog cpp syntax.

I know about explicit branching by if{...}else{...}. But I'm asking about ternan.

Comment: The syntax for casting is always `(typename)expression`.  So `(quint16)(x ? y : z)`.  Don't try to put a ternary expression inside the type parameter of a template though; even if that works it would *have* to be evaluated at compile time.